# Targeting window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have a url similiar to this:

```
www.mysite.com/products/
```

I was using this to test against the pathname:

```
if (/\/products\//.test(window.location)) {
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/products/landing']);
}
```

But the problem I was running into was the above would execute for sub-folders as well, which I do not want:

```
www.mysite.com/products/sub-folder/
```

I'm thinking window.location.pathname will help me out more than the above jQuery. But I'm unsure how to target only the top-level directory, and not the sub directories within it?

Comment: There is not jQuery in your example...

Comment: Why are you using a regex if you want to only test against `/products/`? You could jsut use `if(window.location.pathname == '/products/') {/* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `$` at the end of your regexp:

```
if (/\/products\/$/.test(window.location)) {
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/products/landing']);
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/feK4A/

Comment: How would I do the home page expression? I can't seem to get that one to work?

Comment: @Yahreen what's the url of your homepage? www.mysite.com/?

Comment: Yea but I use a staging server so I'm trying to avoid absolute

Comment: You could use `if(/^\/$/.test(window.location.pathname))` there

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",1);
```

so now you can do

```
var indOf = window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",1);
var myStr = window.location.pathname.substr(0,indOf+1 );

alert( myStr );  // gives you what you want;
```